# How to list Facebook users who like my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I have Facebook page and would like to offer premium services to people which like my page. I use *Graph API Explorer* for testing. I have valid access token.

I try simple HTTP GET, but FB return me only number of likes, not names:

```
GET /123456789 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

{
  "id": "123456789", 
  "about": "example", 
  "can_post": true, 
  "category": "Community", 
  "checkins": 0, 
  "has_added_app": false, 
  "is_community_page": false, 
  "is_published": false, 
  "new_like_count": 1, 
  "likes": 6, 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/example/123456789", 
  "name": "example", 
  "offer_eligible": false, 
  "promotion_eligible": false, 
  "talking_about_count": 0, 
  "unread_message_count": 0, 
  "unread_notif_count": 0, 
  "unseen_message_count": 0, 
  "were_here_count": 0
}
```

FQL query return empty data:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="123456789"
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

How can I get list of names and links to profile? Is it possible? *(On Twitter it is simple.*)

*Update:*
on Groups is possible to use "[/{group-id}/members](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/members/)", it return list of names and ids. But I want page.

Comment: Discussed multiple times before … _not possible_.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `:page/likes` endpoint with the Facebook Graph API, f.ex:

```
GET v2.1/ladygaga/likes
```

Comment: How you do it? I still get `{ "error": "Invalid response" }`

Comment: OK, i see likes which I do it (my page likes LIST_THAT_I_SEE). But I need list of people who likes my page.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood your question and cannot remove my misleading answer! I now also think it isn't possible with the graph API (but you can get the likes of a post...).